# How to add a specific variable label to ggplot facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, variables, label, facet-grid

I am trying to add a specific variable label to certain data points. Eg. indicate the isolate name with more than 0.2 OD in pH 2 category; isolate with more than 0.4 OD in pH 3 category and more than 4.5 OD in pH 6.8 category.

| isolate | pH | OD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 | 0.18 |
| a2 | 2 | 0.25 |
| -------- | -------- |  |
| a3 | 2 | 0.20 |
| a4 | 2 | 0.30 |
| a1 | 3 | 0.3 |
| a2 | 3 | 0.34 |
| a3 | 3 | 0.33 |
| a4 | 3 | 0.41 |
| a1 | 6.8 | 0.49 |
| a2 | 6.8 | 0.25 |
| a3 | 6.8 | 0.46 |
| a4 | 6.8 | 0.34 |

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=isolate, y=OD)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_label( 
    data=data %>% filter(OD>0.2 | pH == "2" , OD>0.4 | pH ==3 , OD > 0.45 | pH == 6.8), # Filter data first
    aes(label=isolate)
      ) +
  facet_grid(.~pH)
```

I tried with the above code but the labels are clumping in one facet grid only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iKDU.png)

Comment: Try with `filter((OD > 0.2 & pH == "2") | (OD > 0.4 & pH == 3) | (OD > 0.45 & pH == 6.8))`.

Comment: Thanks @Stepfan, this code worked. But the 3 labels of each type are displayed instead of one. How do I solve it?